# Unable to get the exact result using stored procedure as it is returning the values with the incrementation

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ado.net

```
ALTER PROCEDURE Searching
    (@EmployeeName varchar(50))    
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT
        EmployeeDetails.EmployeeId, EmployeeName, Mobile, Email, 
        Gender, Married, JoiningDate, DOB, ReportingManager, 
        ISActive, ISDelete, EmployeeRoles.RoleId, 
        employeeDepartment.Department
    FROM
        EmployeeDetails, EmployeeRoles, employeeDepartment
    WHERE
        EmployeeDetails.EmployeeName LIKE '%' + @EmployeeName + '%'
END
```

This is my stored procedure, but when I am executing it I am getting the results as:

```
exec Searching 'Rizwan'
```

[image: The Result I am getting while Executing the Stored Procedure]

So please help me to fix this

Comment: So what results are you expecting?

Comment: @DaleK It is retrieving the Values with the incrementation of roleid column but as that Employee is only given the one roleId and It is incrementing roleID till 3 and retrieving total number of records as the total number of records..
As I am accepting this to return only that value which is present in the table with the single or multiple column as the EmployeeName

Comment: Its probably because your joins are broken. Firstly I recommend not using old style joins, secondly you need to add a join condition for each join.

Comment: @DaleK so can you help me with that query

Comment: I don't know your table definitions or join conditions. How about reading the docs and seeing how you get on. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/joins?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: If you are still stuck you need to add your table definitions and explain the foreign key relationships. However you really are going to want to understand how to do a join yourself, so maybe look up some online tutorials.

Comment: I am doing it if i will stuck then sure

Comment: @DaleK i am using ado.net

Comment: Note: the fact that you're using ado.net and c# is irrelevant here; the problem is purely the query itself

Answer (score 1):

Right now you have unrestricted joins. I can't tell you what your joins *should* be without seeing the schema, but we can speculate something broadly like:

```sql
Alter procedure Searching
(
    @EmployeeName varchar(50)
)    
as 
begin    
    select EmployeeDetails.EmployeeId, EmployeeName, Mobile, Email, Gender, Married, JoiningDate, DOB, ReportingManager, ISActive, ISDelete, e.RoleId, ed.Department
    from EmployeeDetails e
    inner join EmployeeRoles er on er.Id = e.RoleId
    inner join employeeDepartment ed on ed.Id = e.DepartmentId
    where e.EmployeeName LIKE '%' + @EmployeeName + '%'
end
```

Also, as a broad unrelated tip: using `varchar` for human names is usually a bad idea - as is restricting it to 50 characters. Names are important; I'd suggest making it more like `nvarchar(200)` in both the column and the parameter.